# Get all selected value of dropdownlist in comma

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multi select `dropdownlist` in which,

If I selected `3-4 items`, it should get viewed in **commas** one after another.

I tried like this

```
string message = "";
string countItemSelected = "";
foreach (ListItem item in cmbEmp_Name.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        message += item.Value + "\\n";
        countItemSelected = item.Value;
        //Muster_Process();
    }
}

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

but it is not coming in **commas**, how to get that ??

Comment: Because you're adding a newline rather than a comma? What are you using `countItemSelected` for by the way?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: to get the no of items selected. Also, how to write for **commas** ?

Comment: "but it is not coming in commas" How else? What exactly do you mean by comes in ...?

Comment: @coder `message += item.Value + ",";` Your `countItemSelected` just has the value of the last item in the foreach, it's not counting anything

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: yeah, I know that, what's the correct way for getting it ?

Comment: What exactly is the intended behaviour and what do you get instead? Currently it´s quite unclear what you´re asking.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: If u read the question, its clear that, I want a **","** instead of new line. but i am unable to get it. what else you are not getting clear ? kindly let me know

Comment: Then see what Alex alread wrote, it´s exactly what you shuld do.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck; if I try with `message += item.Value + "\\ ,";` it displays me in **","** but after the last value it still gives me  ,

Comment: Replace `\\n` with `,` like everyone has already said....

Comment: You need to trim the last comma after exiting the loop

Comment: @Draken:  I tried with trim `message += item.Value + ",".Trim();` but still getting the comma after last value

Comment: Check posted answer, one possible solution, but sure there are better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
var selItems = cmbEmp_Name.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(x => x.Selected)
    .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
var result = String.Join(",", selItems);
var countItemSelected = selItems.Length;
```

The call to `ToArray` avoids a second iteration of your list when counting the selected items.

Comment: I've asked the OP to use yours as it's a lot better written, nice use of LinQ

Comment: Getting error as `System.Web.UI.WebCotrols.ListItemCollection does not contain a definitio for Where and no extension method where accepting a first argument of type System.Web.UI.WebCotrols.ListItemCollection could be found error is coming`

Comment: do i need to add your code into the `foreach` loop ? or a it's a new set of code ?

Comment: No need for a loop any more, write it instead.

Comment: still getting that same error even after adding the namespace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108904/discussion-between-coder-and-himbrombeere).

Answer (score 1):

```
string message = "";
string countItemSelected = "";
int count = 0;
foreach (ListItem item in cmbEmp_Name.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        if (count > 0)
            message += ",";
        count++;
        message += item.Value;
        //countItemSelected = item.Value;
        //Muster_Process();
    }
}
countItemSelected = count.toString();

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
```

Comment: yeah working, one more thing. how to get the no of  count in `countItemSelected` ?

Comment: As in the number of values selected? If so, you can use the `count` variable I created, that will give you the result you want

Comment: There are possibly more efficient ways of doing this, @Vipul 's looked interesting to use, though not sure on syntax. However if you don't mind quick and dirty, this will solve your problem

Comment: Have a check of @HimBromBeere 's answer, it's using Linq and should be a lot more readable and possibly more efficient

Comment: i am accepting `himbrombeere`'s answer as it is more clear and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var result = cmbEmp_Name
    .Items
    .Where(i => i.Selected)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList()
    .Join(",");
```

Comment: `ToList()` is *redundant* and `Join(",")` is *wrong*. The right syntax is `var result = String.Join(", ", cmbEmp_Name.Items...);`